# Proof of convexity of a function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have to prove that function $J(x)=e^{x^3+x^2+1}$ is convex on $[0,\infty]$.

I used a Theorem which says: **$U\subset R^n$ is convex set with non-empty interior and $J\in C^2(U)$. Function $J$ is convex on $U$ if and only if $\langle J''(u)ξ,ξ\rangle\geq 0$ for all $u\in U$ and all $ξ\in R^n$.

I got that $J''(u)=(6x+2)e^{x^3+x^2+1}+(3x^2+2x)^2e^{x^3+x^2+1}$ which is $\geq 0$ for all $x\ [0,\infty]$.
Hence, $J(u)$ is convex on $[0,\infty]$.

Is this ok?

Comment: Sure. what would the problem be? Your theorem states (it is indeed so) that if the function $f$ has a continuous 2nd derivative, it is convex iff $f''>0$, and you proved the inequality...

Comment: We used this theorem for cases when dimension of space is greater than 1, so I didn't know if I can use it in one-dimensional case. Thanks.

Comment: sure, you can use this result in 1D - in fact, there, it is most intuitive. If you remember the 2nd Derivative Test in Calculus/Analysis, this is how you establish if it is concave up [aka *convex*] or concave down [aka *concave*]

Answer (score 2):

If $g$ is convex, then $\exp \circ g$ is convex ($\exp(x) = e^x$, and $(\exp \circ g)''(x) = e^{g(x)}((g'(x))^2 + g''(x))$, which is clearly non-negative).

If $g(x) = x^3+x^2 +1$, then $g''(x) = 6 x +2$ which is non-negative on $[0,\infty)$.

It follows that $J= \exp \circ g$ is convex (on $[0,\infty)$).